# How include libraries dependencies based on build environnement variant?

Tags: android, gradle, build, environment-variables, build.gradle

I would like to import Android dependencies in the gradle build file and I would like define a  version for all my environnement build variant.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.example.example:test:$version"
}
```

But I would like define a specific version for this dependencies based on build environnement variants like :

```
if (variant == "Eval") {
    version = '1.0.6'
} else if (variant == "Integration") {
    version = '1.0.7'
} else {
    version = '1.0.8'
}
```

How I can implement this feature ?

I have tried this, but don’t work :

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants { variant ->
            def variantName = variant.name
            if (variantName == "Eval") {
                version = '0.1.6'
            } else if (variantName == "Integration") {
                version = '0.1.7'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "com.example.example:test:$version"
}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create custom build variants or custom product flavor. And I can use `${variantName}Implementation`.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        eval1 {}
        eval2 {}
    }
}


dependencies {
    eval1Implementation("com.example.example:test:1.0.0")
    eval2Implementation("com.example.example:test:2.0.0")
}
```